# Findinf data for Binance USDT-M trading commissions on my orders with Binance API

Tags: node.js, binance

I do my work using [Binance NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/binance) with NodeJS.
When I open a long or short market order, how can I find out how much commission is charged for that order?

Also, how can I access the commissions for the order list in my trade history?

I wish you good work